# Creating a Python Program that Looks for the Longest Substring of Characters in Alphabetical Order

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, alphabetical

I am in a Python bootcamp and my first challenge has been to create a program that takes a string, let's say "s=azcbobobegghakl" and indicates which substring has the longest amount of consecutive letters in alphabetical letter. In my example it should output "beggh". I have been putting in a lot of effort and am not looking to use any libraries, just base python. I know there are extremely efficient ways of doing this task, but I am trying to stick with what has been taught in class. Nothing too fancy please. Feel free to just leave a crumb trail for me. Here is what I have so far:

Input:
"

```
s='azcbobobegghakl'
Longest=""
for order in range(len(s)):
    if s[order] >= "a":
        Longest += s[order]
    else: 
        Longest=""
print(Longest):

Output:
"azcbobobegghakl
```

"

So far I have a program that will print the string of letters so long as they're greater or equal to "a", which is all of them. Could someone please help me from here? I understand there are many other solutions out there, but I am just trying to stick with what the class has gone through so far, which would be loops and if statements really. Again, I am not looking for an answer, but some hints please. Thank you!

Comment: Hi, @Luke - is there any constraints of using any Python standard lib. to solve this?

Comment: Maintain two variables - `longest` and `current`. In your loop, keep checking if current index is smaller than next one, if true then add the index to `current`; if false, then update the `longest` with `max(longest, current)`.  This should give you a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

```
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
def longest_alpha(string):
    current = string[0]
    longest = ''
    for idx in range(len(string)-1):
        if alphabet.index(string[idx]) <= alphabet.index(string[idx+1]):
            current += string[idx+1]
        else:
            current = string[idx+1]
        
        if len(current) > len(longest):
            longest = current
    return longest
```

Comment: Very nice and similar to what I was trying to do, at least enough that I could follow. I just needed to add a print statement. Unfortunately it won't work if longest_alpha is z. I'll have to do some more tinkering. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you could try to run this sample and see if you have any questions:

```
s = 'azcbobobegghakl'

from itertools import count

def long_alphabet(string):
    max_substr = ""         # empty slice (to accept subclasses of str)

    N = len(string)
    
    for start in range(N):      # O(n)
        for end in count(start + len(max_substr) + 1):   #
            substr = string[start: end]                     
            
            if len(substr) != (end - start):             #  found sup. or End
                break            
            if sorted(substr) == list(substr):
                max_substr = substr
    return max_substr

ans = (long_alphabet(s))      # beggh <---
print(f"Longest substring in alphabetical order is: {ans} ")
```

Comment: This is really nice looking! I appreciate you taking the time to type this out. There is a lot there that I currently do not know about, but am looking forward to learning. Thanks again